# Fetching env variables in k8s podd

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to pass hostdetails to **k8s podd** .and use it in shell script which is called by cronjob.
Here is example ::

```
env:
      - name: ranger_host
        value: 13455:
and i hv shell script say eg runcron.sh
python2.7 alertMetric.py $ranger_host .
```

But ranger_host is not coming inside thi shell script .Its really hard time to debug .
runcron.sh is called in cronjob as

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * /bin/sh /runcron.sh
```

and when I list env
its deisplayin value inside podd

Comment: I can see what you did but I am sitll not quite sure that is it that you are trying to acheive. Can you be more specific? What did you expect to see? Preferably, also please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), thank you.

Comment: basically I wann environment variables used by shell script

Comment: eg :: sh shellscrpt.sh 13455 ,wherein currently ranger_host is nt fetching value 13455